# Tranformar em json

Tags: php, json, string

Eu tenho uma string:

```
{name:"Sara", daypart:"day", href:"http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", bg:"su", temp:"calor", realfeel:"hot", text:"cloudy"}
```

Basicamente estou à procura de uma forma rápida de transformar isto em JSON, ou seja, pôr aspas (`"`) em cada index (key), para que se torne o JSON válido para depois fazer fazer `json_decode()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de eu não ver necessidade de adicionar `"` na key, porque você vai conseguir trabalhar com o objeto `JSON` da mesma forma, fica aqui uma solução:

```
$json = '{name:"Sara", daypart:"day", href:"http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", bg:"su", temp:"calor", realfeel:"hot", text:"cloudy"}';

$json = preg_replace('/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);    
echo json_encode($json);
```

Saída:

```
"{\"name\":\"Sara\",\"daypart\":\"day\",\"href\":\"http:\/\/pt.stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask\",\"bg\":\"su\",\"temp\":\"calor\",\"realfeel\":\"hot\",\"text\":\"cloudy\"}"
```

Comment: Podia-me explicar o que está a fazer no `preg_replace` sff, e o porquê das "\" no output

Comment: o \ vem do `json_encode` e não do `preg_replace`,

Comment: Sem o `preg_replace` não consigo fazer isso

Comment: @Miguel o `preg_replace` neste caso serve pra colocar os `"` nas suas chaves

Comment: Sim mas tu disseste "Apesar de eu não ver necessidade de adicionar " na key, porque você vai conseguir trabalhar com o objeto JSON da mesma forma...", mas eu estou a ver que sem o `preg_replace` não daria. De qualquer maneira resultou, Muito obrigado outra vez

Comment: @Miguel usando apenas o `json_encode($json);` não deu certo?

Comment: @KaduAmaral o `json_encode` direto não joga `"` nas chaves

Comment: Certo, você está usando o json com que liguagem? Se o que te aflige é as aspas, então a resposta do Maicon é a certa pra você. ;)

Comment: Sim acertou, mas sem o preg_replace (colocação das aspas) não daria, não imprimia nada. Estou a usar com php

Comment: Maicon, o seu `$json` é o que ele quer, e não o `json_encode($json)` (essa última dá a versão "jsonzada" de uma string, não de um objeto). E pessoal, ele quer as aspas na chave senão o JSON fica inválido. A especificação do formato exige as aspas, certo @Miguel?

Comment: Exactamente, eu queria que ficasse JSON para depois o conseguir tranformar em array (`json_decode()`) (PHP) e trabalhar os dados, que sem as aspas não daria, não ficava um JSON válido.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar *javascript* para fazer isso usando `JSON.parse()`

```
JSON.parse('{name:"Sara", daypart:"day", href:"http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", bg:"su", temp:"calor", realfeel:"hot", text:"cloudy"}');
```

Isso vai converter sua `string` e um *JSON* completamente usável

Comment: Não vai não, porque o JSON é inválido (as aspas nas chaves são obrigatórias). Porém, se isso for emitido direto do PHP para o JS, pode ser usado com um objeto literal: `var obj = {name:"Sara", daypart:"day", href:"http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", bg:"su", temp:"calor", realfeel:"hot", text:"cloudy"};`.